# Bounded sum of images of orthonormal basis implies boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This is a problem from Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", problem II.1.3. Suppose $E = \{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space $H$ and $A$ is a linear map $H \to K$ (where $K$ is also a Hilbert space) that satisfies $\sum_n \| Ae_n\| < \infty $. Show that $A$ is bounded.

I believe the statement to be false in general. Let $H=l^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $K = \mathbb{R}$. We can extend $E$ to a Hamel basis $E'$ such that $\|e\| = 1$ for all $e \in E'$. Let $(f_n)$ be any enumerable subset of $E' \setminus E$. Then setting $Ae_n = 2^{-n}$, $Af_n = n$ and $Ae = 0$ for $e \in E' \setminus (E \cup (f_n))$ yields an unbounded operator on $H$. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: I am extending it to Hamel basis, not an orthonormal basis. I'm merely normalising them to ensure that all the basis vectors fall within the unit ball, but they will not be orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is fine. But the exercise does not ask what you say it asks. It says to show that $A$ has a unique bounded extension. Your example produces an unbounded extension; that doesn't preclude the existence of a bounded one.

[image]

.

Comment: The problem (in the version of the book I have) explicitly states that the domain of $A$ is already given to be $H$, not $\operatorname{span}(e_n)$. If it is densely defined then it has a unique continuous extension that happens to be linear, but the problem (quoted nearly verbatim above) doesn't ask for this.

Comment: But thank you for verifying the example!

Comment: You have a very old version, then: I have included a screenshot of the 1989 version.

Comment: Looks like you're right - my version is from 1985. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct but you should mention explicitly that a Hilbert space cannot have a countable Hamel basis (which is not a trivial result). That is the reason why your sequence $(f_n)$ exists.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I should have explicitly mentioned that. In fact I'd like to check if this works for non-separable Hilbert space as well, but I am not sure if such spaces have Hamel bases with strictly greater cardinality than their dimension.